# Should I use express as a dependency with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, package.json

I have a react app with webpack, and a node.js backend server with express for backend.

My question is:
Should I create 2 `package.json` for each one and install their dependencies. Or I should just create `package.json` and install every dependencies into its.

What option should I follow? Which is better in terms of performance? Help is appreciated

Comment: You should have two separate projects.... a frontend project and a backend project. If somebody only needs to work on the frontend they don't have to install express and other backend dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, but write a response and I'll reputate you